# K theory of projectionless C*-algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Is it possible to have a projectionless C*- algebra with non trivial K-theory? If so what would be such an example? I can't come up with any.

p.s.

By projectionless I mean non-unital aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is given by $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$.  This has no non-zero projections, and by Bott periodicity, we have 
\begin{align*}
K_n(C_0(\mathbb R^2))=K_n(\mathbb C)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb Z &:n=0,\\
0 &:n=1.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry I just started learning K-theory, how did you find $K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))=K_0(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Because $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$ is the second suspension of $\mathbb C$ (i.e., $C_0(\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb C\otimes\mathbb C_0(\mathbb R)\otimes C_0(\mathbb R)=S^2\mathbb C$), and thus $$K_0(C_0(\mathbb R^2))=K_2(\mathbb C)=K_0(\mathbb C),$$ where the first equality is essentially a definition, and the last is Bott periodicity

Comment: Or, maybe slightly simpler, because $K$-theory is homotopy-invariant. In particular, you get the same result for any contractible locally compact space $X$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @MaoWao But you have to be careful with homotopies of non-compact locally compact spaces.  Only when they are proper do they induce homotopies on their function algebras.

Comment: @Aweygan You are right. Now that you say I remember that there was some sublety.