# K- theory of stably projectionless C* algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

could anyone give me an example of a stably projectionless C*-algebra with non-zero $K_0$ group?

Comment: You can actually realize any pair $(G_0,G_1)$ and Choquet-simplex $\Delta$ as the K-theory resp. trace simplex of a simple,nuclear,separable,stably projetionless, $\mathcal Z$-stable C*-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$ provides such an example.  Based on the answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105256/k-theory-of-projectionless-c-algebras), $K_0(C_0(\mathbb R^2)=\mathbb Z$ is nontrivial. To show that $C_0(\mathbb R^2)$ is stably projectionless, consider any map $f:\mathbb R^2\to M_n(\mathbb C)$, vanishing at infinity, with $f(x)$ a projection for all $x\in\mathbb R^2$.  Since any nontrivial projection has norm $1$, and $\mathbb R^2$ is connected, it follows that $f=0$, and the result follows.

Comment: Projectionless also means A is non unital and hence you have to consider the unitization of A where new projections may arise!

Comment: Forgive me for the mistake.  I will edit when I find a solution.

Comment: Doesn't your answer in a similar question also answer this?

Comment: @minimalrho If that algebra is stably projectionless, then yes.

Comment: The rank map is continuous on projections in $M_n$. So given a projection in $M_n(C_0(X))$, one obtains a continuous map $X \to P(M_n) \to \mathbb{Z}$. If $X$ is connected, then this map must be constant. As an element of $M_n(C_0(X))$, the projection must therefore be zero. I think this works?

Comment: I just realized this, typing up a solution now.  Thanks.